# json key:...,value:.... to value_key:value_value in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, jsonb

how can I change a list of jsonb structure (key/value) to object, dynamically??

for example:

from

`[{'key':'size','value':'200'},{'key':'pound','value':'200'},{'key':'square','value':'true'},...]`

to

`{'size':'200','pound':'200','square':'true',....}`

```
select jsonb_array_elements( topi.other_information)->'key' as key_field,
jsonb_array_elements( topi.other_information)->'value' as value_field
from items_data.tbl_items topi
```

but when I use `jsonb_build_object` i need to know the keys. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unnest the array then aggregate it back using `jsonb_object_agg()`

```
select t.id, jsonb_object_agg(x ->> 'key', x -> 'value')
from items_data.tbl_items t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.other_information) as x(element)
group by t.id
```

`t.id` is the assumed primary key of the table which is needed to keep the values for the same row together during unnesting and grouping.

---

If you need that frequently, maybe it makes sense to write a function:

```
create function flatten(p_input jsonb)
  returns jsonb
as
$$
  select jsonb_object_agg(x ->> 'key', x -> 'value')
  from jsonb_array_elements(p_input) as x(element);
$$
language sql
immutable;
```

Then you can use it without a group by:

```
select t.id, flatten(t.other_information)
from items_data.tbl_items t
```

Comment: Because I just finished the same solution: here's my fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=329ff64332124f20bca56eeec29ad26d

Comment: .... i was trying to do the same thing with "with"... 
```
with temp_table_items as (
select id,jsonb_array_elements( topi.other_information)->>'key' as key_field,
jsonb_array_elements( topi.other_information)->>'value' as value_field,item_number,group_number,quantity,unit_value,total_value,brand,
model_version,manufacturer,item_final_details
from items_data.tbl_items topi
)
select id,jsonb_build_object('is_foreign', case when key_field='is_foreign' and value_field = 'true' then true else false end...```


thank you so much!!!! it works nice your query is much better. thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name thank you! you save my day